# Cast varchar to an integer in Teradata

Tags: teradata

here is what i have:

SELECT * FROM Trans
WHERE TRANSID IN (

select CAST(TRIM(FIRSTNAME) AS INT)  from Customer
where trim(firstname) between '0' and '9999999999999999'
AND custid not in
(select custid from address) )

Have numerical values in this firstname column that i have to trace back to the trans table, in which the values in the firstname column are transid's.

getting an error:  SELECT Failed. 2620: The format or data contains a bad character

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE fails because it's true for '0foo', too.

What's your Teradata release?

In TD14 you could use a Regular Expression:

```
WHERE regexp_instr(trim(firstname), '^[0-9]+$') > 0
```

Before you need a UDF, eIsInteger or eIsBigInt are some of the [Ebay UDFs](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/madmac/2010/03/a-few-basic-scalar-string-udfs)

Comment: Thank you, Dnoeth... I used the where clause you provided and received an error message : SELECT Failed, 2616: Numeric overflow occured during computation..

Comment: "Numeric overflow" means the value didn't fit in an INTEGER, try BIGINT or NUMBER instead.